# using javascript onload() and ajax to retrieve php array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using onload() and ajax to get the array from php, but it didnt work. The html page should be able to get the array from n1.php and  alert("GOOD"), but it's not giving any response, not even alerting GOOD or BAD so i really dont know what's wrong with the code. How can I fix this??

**n1.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="getArr();">
here
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">             
function getArr(){              
    alert('return sent');   
    $.ajax({
        url: "n1.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json_data){
        var data_array = $.parseJSON(json_data);
        var rec = data_array[0];
        alert("GOOD");
        },
        error: function() {
        alert("BAD");
        }
    });                 
}
 </script></html>
```

**n1.php:**

```
<?php
    $output = array("cat","dog");
    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: You do not need to parse JSON if you have specified `dataType: json`. Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: Are these the console error?? Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : n1.html:7
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < www.serversfree.com/:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: getArr is not defined n1.html:2

Comment: Have you included jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request must contains the type of request. Also the dataType refers on data you are going to send,as long as you don't send any data, it does not need here.
Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "n1.php",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(json_data){
    var data_array = $.parseJSON(json_data);
    var rec = data_array[0];
    alert("GOOD");
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("BAD");
  }
});
```

Comment: Default type is GET in jquery ajax So it does not matter if 'GET' is not passed in AJAX. I don't think setting type to 'GET' solves the problem. It is removing of 'dataType' which solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "n1.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json_data){
    var data_array = json_data; // Do not parse json_data because dataType is 'json'
    var rec = data_array[0];
    alert("GOOD");
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("BAD");
  }
});
```

Now, two things to note here:

1. You have not passed HTTP Method in the ajax but by default it is `GET` as mentioned [here in jQuery AJAX docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Please pass appropriate method type if it is not `GET`.
2. Since you have sent `dataType` as 'json', you need not parse json received in the response in success handler.